# WATCH not working with Visual Studio Code, is that a bug?

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, visual-studio-code, watch

I am developing using React Native on Visual Studio Code and recently my watch stopped working, and now it keeps telling that variables (most of them) are *`not available`*.

For example, for the below code:

```
MyFunc()
{
    let fromDate = new Date(2017,4,24) 
    let toDate = new Date(2017,4,26)            
    let daysInDifference = Math.round((toDate.valueOf()-fromDate.valueOf())/(1000*60*60*24)) + 1;  

    for(let i = 0; i < daysInDifference; i++)
    {   
        let Result = SomeFunction()

        if(Result.length === 0) // everything is fine till here
        {
            let MyVariable = [];

            for(let i = 0; i < daysInDifference; i++)
            {     
                // ..
```

I can step over until the `if()` statement, and watch all fine:
 [image]

But if I step over the `if()` statement, the debugger takes me to `index.ios.bundle` and comes back with the WATCH broken:

Bundle:
[image]

Notice when it comes back, variable `toDate` (and many others I did not show) is "available" under `VARIABLES -> Closure`, but not under `WATCH`:

[image]

Tried to do:

- Installed most recent Visual Studio Code
- Reinstalled all plugins
- Restarted machine a million times

Debugging with the VARIABLES is a pain in the as**, please any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted VS + Machine, and then everything went back to normal.